# frequency response multistage

Tags: frequency, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

hello every one i need ask about frequency response i have an old question of our professor exam in few year, and i try to solve this question many time but i can't so please if any one have idea about it,i know that in LOW the externaly capcitor is effect and at high the internail capacitor is effect C_miller in and C_miller out,but how i can show the frequency response without poles and zero and how i know how many zeroes and poles in figure?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I can help you is the following:

- Low frequency: C as open
- High frequency: C as short
- Poles: everywhere where there are high impedance nodes, that is, gate or drain nodes. For every pole the frequency roll-off is -20 dB as indicated here: https://payhip.com/b/5Srt (Fig. 1.26 - click preview to see it).